# Prove that $|f(z)|\leq |z|^2$ where $f$ is analytic on the unit disc and has a zero of order 2 at zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is analytic on the unit disk $|z|<1$. If $f(z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at the origin and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the disk. Prove that $|f(z)|\leq |z|^2$ when $|z|<1$.

What I did:

Since $f(z)$ is analytic on the unit disk, so $f(z)$ has the Taylor series representation $\sum a_nz^n$.

And since $f(z)$ has a zero of order $2$, $a_0=a_1=0$, so $f(z)=a_2z^2+a_3z^3+......$

Since $|f(z)|\leq1$, so $|f(z)|=|a_2z^2+a_3z^3+......|\leq1$, then I stuck...

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  Just so you know you can upvote and/or accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $r>0$ let $D_r$ be the closed disk of radius $r$.

First note $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$ has a removable singularity at $0$ so extends to an analytic function on the unit disk.  Now by maximum modulus principal when $0<r<1$ the maximum of $g$ on $D_r$ occurs when $|z|=r$.  When $|z|=r$ we have $|g(z)|\leq \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^2}\leq \frac{1}{r^2}$.  Letting $r\to 1^-$ we have $|g(z)|\leq 1$.  Hence $|f(z)|\leq|z|^2$ on the unit disk.