# How to choose a sqrt branch such that the function will be analytic at $0$? - Complex analysis - Schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I have a question:
$f:\:Ball_2\left(0\right)\rightarrow Ball_2\left(0\right)$
$f\left(0\right)=f'\left(0\right)=0$
Prove: $\left|f\left(z\right)\right|\le \frac{1}{2}\left|z\right|^2$
My way of proving:
Define: $g\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}f\left(2z\right)\right)},\:g:\:Ball_1\left(0\right)\rightarrow Ball_1\left(0\right)$
$g\left(0\right)=0$
Thus, by the Schwarz lemma we receive:
$\left|g\left(z\right)\right|\le \left|z\right|\:\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}f\left(2z\right)\right)}\le \left|z\right|\:\Leftrightarrow \left|f\left(2z\right)\right|\le 2\left|z\right|^2$
And now If I define: $\tilde{\left\{z\right\}=}\:2z\:$
we receive:
$$\left|f\left(z\right)\right|\le \frac{1}{2}\left|z\right|^2$$

My problem here only, is with how to define $g(z)$ so it will be "right".
Because it does not have any derivative at $z=0$, so I have to define it somehow with the branches.
Someone have any way of doing it?

I know, there is a way to do solution without the sqrt, but I still wish to continue to do so.

Comment: What are you using the subscript on the balls to represent?

Comment: what do you mean? you mean the $Ball_2\left(0\right)$? if yes, so it is a disc with a radius of 2, which its center at $z_0 = 0$

Comment: You wont, if $f$ has a zero of odd order at $z=0$. You could modify your argument to work using a square root of $h(z)$, where $f(z)=z^mh(z)$ and $h(0)\neq0$.

Comment: @NDB Actually, I tried working with the sentence of the zeros, sadly it did not help me reach somewhere :\. f has an order of 2, which means I can do as you said: $f(z)=g(z) \cdot z^2$, but it wont really help, since I can not know anything about the range of $g(z)$

Comment: $f$ has a zero of order at least $2$, but it could be larger and odd.

Comment: Yea, atleast two, but it can not help me sadly:\ I tried :(

Comment: *“I know, there is a way to do solution without the sqrt, but I still wish to continue to do so.”* – I am afraid that you are on a wrong path. The function may not have a holomorphic square root because it can have zeros of odd order, e.g. $f(z) = c z^2 (1-z)$.

Comment: Ahh, there is not a way to fix this? Sadly I have no other idea on how to do this. I tried maybe with $g(z)$ without the sqrt, there I don't have the problem of singularity at $z=0$, but could not think of anything. Thanks though for the help :)

Comment: Just saw the example, yep... :(

Comment: What you should do is to use, instead of Schwartz's lemma, use the idea in its proof. I suppose that is the way you said you know about.

Comment: @NDB what way? the only 2 ways I thought are: 1. Schwartz's Lemma with sqrt ( wrong sadly ) and 2. using the same $g(z)$ function, but without sqrt and using order of zeros, but it didn't help me also :\ I got stuck pretty fast, since I can not know anything regarding the range of the analytic function I create because of the zeros sentence

Comment: After scaling $f$ to a mapping from the unit disk into itself this becomes https://math.stackexchange.com/q/779792/42969

Comment: Oh thanks, I will try it and update :)

Comment: I thought you knew how to do it without the square root approach. Here is one way, which is just imitating the proof of Schwartz's lemma. Take $h(z)=f(z)/z^2$ extended to $z=0$. For $r<2$ and $|z|=r$, by the Maximum Modulus principle, there is $z_r$ with $|z_r|=r$ such that $|h(z)|\leq |h(z_r)|=|f(z_r)||z_r|^{-2}\leq 2r^{-2}$. Taking limit as $r\to 2^-$ we get $|f(z)/z^2|=|h(z)|\leq 2/4$. And this is the inequality $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}|z|^2$

Comment: God lord, that proof looks good, but really problematic, all those $H(Z_r)$, it might take me a while to understand, Huge Thanks!!!

Comment: @MartinR Just did the solution your way, it worked! Thanks!!
I just saw that actually the way is close, so now I understood it pretty much good, Thanks to all of you :)